# Delay jquery redirect

Tags: jquery, function, redirect, delay

I've seen some functions with normal javascript here on stackoverflow, regarding my question.
Although I haven't seen anything that will delay the redirect function which I have here.

```
    if(data=='success'){
        $('form').fadeOut();
        $('#status').addClass('noti-success').html('Please wait while we redirect you...').slideDown();
        redirect("?i=a");
    }
```

As you can see, it will redirect immediately to ?i=a, and therefore makes the notifiction message only show for a second or so.

How can I delay the redirect function with X number of seconds?

Comment: It looks silly to show the notification message for just a second. Un behalf of client request, he wishes that the user is able to read the message.

Comment: So don't show a notification, and just show the new page… [*scratches head*].

Comment: As said, the client wishes to show a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the redirect after the message was hidden:

```
$('#status')
  .addClass('noti-success')
  .html('Please wait while we redirect you...')
  .delay(2000)
  .slideDown(function() {
      redirect("?i=a");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout` to delay the redirect:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { redirect("?i=a"); }, 1000);
```